# Can't download dependency artifact from release repo

Tags: maven, deployment, artifactory, maven-release-plugin

I am building a maven project which inherits a parent module.

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.xxx.dist</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.xxx.dist.core.msp.service.pom</artifactId>
        <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> <!-- 0.1 for release -->
    </parent>
    <artifactId>com.lgc.dist.core.msp.service.kafka</artifactId>
```

The artifacts of parent `com.xxx.dist.core.msp.service.pom` is published in both snapshot repository (version 0.1-SNAPSHOT) and release repository (version 0.1).

`mvn deploy` is run for deploying snapshot. The parent pom can be downloaded successfully:

```
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.openearth.community/artifactory/distarch-maven-snapshots/com/xxx/dist/com.xxx.dist.core.msp.service.pom/0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.openearth.community/artifactory/distarch-maven-snapshots/com/xxx/dist/com.xxx.dist.core.msp.service.pom/0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (599 B at 1.9 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.openearth.community/artifactory/distarch-maven-snapshots/com/xxx/dist/com.xxx.dist.core.msp.service.pom/0.1-SNAPSHOT/com.xxx.dist.core.msp.service.pom-0.1-20170726.184445-38.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.openearth.community/artifactory/distarch-maven-snapshots/com/xxx/dist/com.xxx.dist.core.msp.service.pom/0.1-SNAPSHOT/com.xxx.dist.core.msp.service.pom-0.1-20170726.184445-38.pom (14 KB at 664.4 KB/sec)
```

For release build with maven release plugin though, it does not seem to be able to download the parent pom from release repo:

```
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.openearth.community/artifactory/distarch-maven-snapshots/com/xxx/dist/com.xxx.dist.core.msp.service.pom/0.1/com.xxx.dist.core.msp.service.pom-0.1.pom
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.openearth.community/artifactory/distarch-maven-staging/com/xxx/dist/com.xxx.dist.core.msp.service.pom/0.1/com.xxx.dist.core.msp.service.pom-0.1.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.xxx.dist:com.xxx.dist.core.msp.service.kafka:[unknown-version]: Could not transfer artifact com.xxx.dist:com.lgc.dist.core.msp.service.pom:pom:0.1 from/to snapshots (https://repo.openearth.community/artifactory/distarch-maven-snapshots): Failed to transfer file: https://repo.openearth.community/artifactory/distarch-maven-snapshots/com/xxx/dist/com.xxx.dist.core.msp.service.pom/0.1/com.xxx.dist.core.msp.service.pom-0.1.pom. Return code is: 409 , ReasonPhrase:Conflict. and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 4, column 10
```

It tried to look for the artifact in both repos which are defined in `settings.xml` of maven, `distarch-maven-snapshots` and `distarch-maven-staging`. The error may be a little bit misleading, because it was referring to not being able to transfer from snapshots repo instead of release. I've seen this before and it just means it could not transfer from either `snapshots` or `staging`.

The 0.1 pom does exist in staging repo
[image: artifactory]
And if I just paste the whole url `https://repo.openearth.community/artifactory/distarch-maven-staging/com/xxx/dist/com.xxx.dist.core.msp.service.pom/0.1/com.xxx.dist.core.msp.service.pom-0.1.pom` in a browser, I could display the pom file. Both `snapshots` and `staging` repoes are set up in the same Artifactory. What could be the reason that I can't pull from release repo while snapshot repo works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that for some reason the POM is named wrong:

> com.lgc.dist.core.msp.service.pom-0.1.pom

It should be named:

> com.lgc.dist.core.msp.service-0.1.pom

As you can see you have " .pom-0.1.pom " which should be "-0.1.pom"

Can you try to change that and see if that works?